# Form submitting automatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I have a form that works correctly, but under certain testing conditions it does not. The form is an update form that updates the user's information. It does not refresh the page and it uses jQuery's validation plugin. Whenever I go on the page, and change my username to something that's already taken, it does not notify me that it's been taking (I haven't clicked out of the form for it to update). Let's say I don't click out of the form and I go and click the submit button. It'll say that my username is already taken and I can't update it until I choose a different username. Now when I go to change it, it'll automatically submit the form for me when I found a username that's not taken.

How do I fix it so that the user has to submit the form again in order for it to actually update? I've tried returning false on the else statements, but I can't seem to find the solution.

**Validation code**

```
    $(".personal_form").validate({
errorElement: 'div',
rules: {
    firstName: {
        required: true,
        minlength: 2,
        maxlength: 20
    },

    lastName: {
        required: true,
        minlength: 2,
        maxlength: 20
    },

    bio: {
        maxlength: 100
    },

    email: {
        required: true,
        maxlength: 100,
        email: true,
        remote: {
            url: "usernameChecker.php",
                type: "post",
                data: {
                  email: function() {
                    return $( "#email" ).val();
                    },
                },
        },
    },



    username: {
        required: true,
        maxlength: 15,
        alphanumeric: true,
        remote: {
            url: "usernameChecker.php",
                type: "post",
                data: {
                  username: function() {
                    return $( "#username" ).val();
                    },
                },
            },
    },
},

messages: {

    firstName: {
        required: "Please enter your first name.",
        minlength: "Your name should be greater than one letter.",
        maxlength: "Your name should not exceed 20 characters."
    },

    lastName: {
        required: "Please enter your last name.",
        minlength: "Your last name should be greater than one letter.",
        maxlength: "Your last name should not exceed 20 characters"
    },

    bio: {
        maxlength: "Your bio should not exceed 100 characters."
    },

    email: {
        required: "Please enter an email.",
        maxlength: "Your email should not exceed 100 characters.",
        email: "Please enter a valid email.",
        remote: "This email is already taken."
    },

    username: {
        required: "Please enter a username.",
        maxlength: "Your username should not exceed 15 characters.",
        alphanumeric: "Usernames should contain only letters, numbers or underscores.",
        remote: "This username is taken."
    },

},

});
```

**Submission code**

```
        $('.personal_form').on('submit', function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        $(".submit_btn").val("UPDATING...");
        $(".submit_btn").css("background-color", "gray");
        $(".submit_btn").prop("disabled", true);

          if ($('.personal_form').valid()) {

            $.ajax({
              url: "usernameChecker.php",
              type: "POST",
              data: {
                username: $('#username').val()
              },
              success: function(data) {
                if (data == "true") {
                  $.ajax({
                    url: "usernameChecker.php",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: {
                      email: $('#email').val()
                    },
                    success: function(data) {
                      if (data == "true") {

                        $.ajax({
                          type: 'POST',
                          url: '',
                          data: $('.personal_form').serialize(),
                          success: function(data) {
                            success();
                            submit_failed();
                            $(".mob_profile_menu a").attr("href", "/profiles/" + $("#username").val());
                            $(".profile_banner a").attr("href", "/profiles/" + $("#username").val());
                            $(".linker").attr("href", "/profiles/" + $("#username").val());

                          }
                        });
                      }

                      else{
                           submit_failed();
                      }
                    }
                  });
                }

                else{
                    submit_failed();
                }
              }
            });
          }

          else{
            submit_failed();
          }
        });


       function submit_failed(){
        $(".submit_btn").val("Submit Details");
        $(".submit_btn").removeAttr('style');
        $(".submit_btn").prop("disabled", false);
        }
```

Comment: Your issue and provided code doesn't match up. I don't see anything **jQuery's validation plugin** code, where is it?

Comment: @Jai I have added the validation code please check

Answer (score 0):

[Your ajax only belongs inside of the `submitHandler` callback provided within `.validate()`](https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#submithandler), not within your own external `.on('submit')` handler.  Since the plugin is already handling the submit event, this could explain your unpredictable behavior.

```
$(document).ready(function() {          // DOM ready
    $('#yourform').validate({           // initialize plugin
        // rules, options, etc.
        submitHandler: function(form) { // fires when form is valid
            $.ajax({ .... });           // ajax submit
            return false;               // block default submit
        }
    });
});
```

As a side-note, you do **not** need the `data` parameter for your `remote` rule because the value of this field is already being sent by default.

```
email: { // <- value of this field is sent by remote
    required: true,
    maxlength: 100,
    email: true,
    remote: {
        url: "usernameChecker.php",
        type: "post", 
    },
},
```

Comment: So something like this would do the trick? `$(".personal_form").validate({
    submitHandler: function(form) {
      $(form).ajaxSubmit();
    }
    
  });`

Comment: @user2896120, yes, except `ajaxSubmit` depends on yet another plugin.